# Grouping results based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to group the results by "*SSN*". The results will then be looped over to show in the View. I'm very new to this and not sure what's the right way to go in solving this issue. I'm not sure how much code I should be showing in here. Let me know if you want to see more code. Please if someone can take a look at the error and provide some assistance.

**Error Message:**

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0029  Cannot
>   implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' CardDistroE:\wwwroot\CardDistro\CardDistro\Controllers\CardsController.cs   119

*CardController.cs*

```
    List<Card> QueriedBatchList;
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
    QueriedBatchList = db.Cards.Where(x => x.BatchID == null).GroupBy(x => x.SSN).ToList();

    CardViewModel CardViewModel = new CardViewModel();
    List<CardViewModel> CardDataList = QueriedBatchList.Select(x => new CardViewModel
    {
        CardID = x.CardID,
        SSN = x.SSN,
        PortID = x.PortID,
        UserID= x.UserID,
        Created= x.Created,
    }).ToList();
```

*CardViewModel.cs*

```
public class CardViewModel
{
    public int CardID { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public int PortID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TransactionID { get; set; }
    public int AddedUserID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BatchID { get; set; }

    public virtual Card Cards1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Card Card1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Batch Batch { get; set; }
    public virtual Port Port { get; set; }
    public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply `Select` after grouping. You should select `Card` entity collection. For example:

```
QueriedBatchList = db.Cards
    .Where(x => x.BatchID == null)
    .GroupBy(x => x.SSN)
    .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

This query will group `Cards` by `SSN` and select the first record of each group.